# Set partitions with big blocks - real-rooted polynomials?

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, recurrences

The polynomials
$$
T_n(t) := \sum_{\pi \in \text{Set Partitions}(n)} t^{\text{blocks}(\pi)} = \sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k)t^k
$$
with $S(n,k)$ being the Stirling numbers of the second kind, are well-known to be real-rooted. For example, the recursion for Stirling numbers translates to the recursion
$$
T_n(x) = x \cdot  T_{n-1}(x) + x\cdot T'_{n-1}(x)
$$
and from this, it is easy to show that all $T_n$ are real-rooted, and form a Sturm sequence. (One can also show that $x^n T_n(x^{-1})$ are rook polynomials of the staircase chessboard and deduce realrootedness from this).

Now, what if we extend the above definition to
$$
T_{n,j}(t) := \sum_{\pi \in \text{Set Partitions}(n)} t^{\text{blocks}_j(\pi)}
$$
where $blocks_j(\pi)$ now only count the number of blocks containing at least $j$ elements.

If we set $Q_{n,j}(t)=t T_{n,j}(t)$, then one can show that one has the recursion
$$
 Q_{n+1,j} = t\cdot Q'_{n,j} + \sum_{k=1}^{j-2} \binom{n}{k} Q_{n-k,j}
 + t\cdot  \binom{n}{j-1} Q_{n-(j-1),j}.
$$
This is the analog of the recursion above using the Stirling numbers.

**Conjecture:** All $Q_{n,j}(t)$ (and $T_{n,j}(t)$) are real-rooted.

**Conjecture (stronger):** The $Q_{n,j}(t)$ interlaces each of the polynomials
$Q_{n-1,j}(t),Q_{n-2,j}(t),\dotsc,Q_{n-j,j}(t)$.

For $j=2$, this result follows (after some bijections) from a theorem on [descents run-sorted permutations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.04220) (thm 16).

For larger $j$, the recursion is a bit too long to apply the obvious standard methods, unfortunately. But, perhaps one can realize these as matching polynomials also?

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem would be appreciated!